# Undefined Object in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new to programming and following instructions in a couple of books and the wordpress codex. I am attempting to access a custom database using the $wpdb object. This is being done locally. I get the following error.

> Notice: Undefined property: wpdb::$national_re_trends in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 68

Also get this:

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]
>   SELECT * FROM

Here is the query:

```
global $wpdb;                       
$stuff = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->national_re_trends" );
print_r($stuff);
```

Here is my database table:

[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L5mZ.jpg)

I am sure this is some newb stuff but if someone could help, I would be grateful!

Comment: this may provide some help [stack exchange using wpdb](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110677/get-results-using-wpdb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "built-in" WordPress table referred to as `national_re_trends`, so `$wpdb->national_re_trends` will not exist.  ([Here is a list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table_Overview) of the 11 built-in WP tables).

Instead, you have to access the table via the name you've assigned to it.

Typically, I like to define a constant, something like so so that it gets the table prefix built into it (of course, if you didn't include the table prefix when you created the table, you'd want to take that into consideration and remove the $table_prefix below).

```
global $table_prefix;
define( 'MY_TABLE_NAME', $table_prefix . 'national_re_trends' );
```

Then, your query would look something like so:

```
global $wpdb;
$stuff = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM ' . MY_TABLE_NAME );
var_dump( $stuff );
```

Comment: I very much appreciate the help. This worked perfectly. Is there an advantage to defining it this way? Thx so much!

Comment: The advantage to defining a constant is that the constant is available to all functions, classes, etc. that you may write (a variable would not be available inside of functions without using `global`, whereas a constant **is**).  Using a constant like this makes the code more maintainable, because if you simply type the name of the table into every query that you write, if you ever need to change the table name you'll have to change it in every separate query.  If you define a constant like I suggest, you'd only have to change the table name in ONE place - where you defined the constant.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and answer. I will implement.

Answer (score 0):

If `dhe_` is your table prefix, remove `$wpdb` after the FROM.

```
  global $wpdb;                       
  $stuff = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM dhe_national_re_trends" );
  print_r($stuff);
```

If you want to use $wpdb->prefix

```
global $wpdb;                       
  $stuff = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}national_re_trends" );
  print_r($stuff);
```

Comment: I mistakenly added that when copied and posted here. Originally had it just like you had it and still got the error.

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Baffles me the 2 books I am referencing do not mention this. Thank you so much!